# Scraping data from multiple tooltips using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape the Hydrogen Sulfide data from this [website](https://marathonlosangelesrefineryfencelinemonitoring.com/) using Python and Selenium. What I have been struggling so far is I do not know how to get the data for each tooltip(site id, site name, date, value, unit, etc.). As you can see, we have seven monitoring points ranging from A to
G and each point corresponds to its own data. I have done lots of research and still got stuck. I have compiled the following codes to scrape the data on a specific date but encountered errors. Please see my codes below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager(log_level=20).install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://marathonlosangelesrefineryfencelinemonitoring.com/index.html")

# Navigate to monitors
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='nav-link-text']")   
button.click()

# Navigate to dropdown button
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='arrow-down parameter-arrow']") 
dropdown.click()

# Select Hydrogen Sulfide and click
h2s = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu' and @role='menu' and @aria-labelledby='ParameterDropdown']//li[12]")
h2s.click()

res = []
test = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane']//div[contains(@class, 'leaflet-marker-icon')]")
for ele in test:
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ele)
    hover.perform()
    try:
        site_id = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-site-id > p")
        site_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-site-name")
        date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-localtime")
        value = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-data-value")
        unit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-data-unit")
        para_mdl = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".tooltip-parameter-mdl")
        res.append((site_id.text, site_name.text, date.text, value.text, unit.text, para_mdl.text))
    except:
        pass
```

I really appreciate if anyone can help me resolve this issue. Also, I want to scrape data on a time window (let's say from Aug 1st, 2021 to Jan 1st, 2022) by leveraging the codes above, so any feedbacks are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all your code needed were some WebdriverWaits. React-based websites are a bit difficult on automating due to a lot of aysncs if I am not wrong and due to the virtual DOM. I have refactored your code with WebdriverWaits as required (and also eliminated multiple lines, although you may retain them if you want a better readability). Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager(log_level=20).install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://marathonlosangelesrefineryfencelinemonitoring.com/index.html")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='nav-link-text']"))).click()
# Navigate to monitors
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='arrow-down parameter-arrow']"))).click()
# Navigate to dropdown button
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='dropdown-menu' and @role='menu' and @aria-labelledby='ParameterDropdown']//li[12]"))).click()
# Select Hydrogen Sulfide and click
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane']//div[contains(@class, 'leaflet-marker-icon')]")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".arrow-down.date-arrow").click()
req_month = 'Aug'
req_year = '2021'
req_timeline = req_month + " " + req_year
print(f"Timeline Selected is: {req_timeline}")
for i in range(11):
    month = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//th[@class='month']").text
    if month == req_timeline:
        break
    else:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//th[@class='prev available']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='table-condensed']//td[text()='1']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Apply']").click()
time.sleep(8)
res = []
test = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane']//div[contains(@class, 'leaflet-marker-icon')]")
for ele in test:
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ele)
    hover.perform()
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        site_id = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-site-id > p")
        site_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-site-name")
        date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-localtime")
        value = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-data-value")
        unit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-data-unit")
        para_mdl = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".tooltip-parameter-mdl")
        res.append((site_id.text, site_name.text, date.text, value.text, unit.text, para_mdl.text))
    except:
        pass
print(res)
```

Here is the result:

```
Timeline Selected is: Aug 2021
[('F', 'Point Monitor', '7:55 AM', '1.80', 'ppb', 'MDL: 0.40 ppb'), ('B', 'Point Monitor', '7:55 AM', '1.20', 'ppb', 'MDL: 0.40 ppb'), ('E', 'Point Monitor', '7:55 AM', '1.10', 'ppb', 'MDL: 0.40 ppb'), ('A', 'Point Monitor', '7:55 AM', '0.40', 'ppb', 'MDL: 0.40 ppb')]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

You see even there are WebdriverWaits introduced, some places needed that hard stop on `time.sleep`, otherwise the tests are getting flaky.

Comment: Anand, I really appreciate your time and efforts. Your codes worked like a charm and I learned a lot from them. Just a quick follow-up that if you have any suggestions/pointers on how to automate scraping data for multiple days (say from Aug 1st, 2021 to Jan 1st, 2022). Thanks!

Comment: @ThaiNguyen Do you have any api that you can use get data? If yes, then prefer that, for I as far as I see, there is no 'data range' to pick data from 1 Aug 21 to 1 Jan 22). We have to click on the calendar of each month and then get data for each day (If I am not wrong).
I will modify the code above to add the calendar picks though for you to have a look.

Comment: So, in order for you to take data for each month (say 1st of every month), you have to loop through each of the month and fetch data until you reach 1 Jan 22.
It would be easy if you could get the data from the backend (say, through an API if you have one)

Comment: Anand, unfortunately there is no API available for this website and you were absolutely right that I had to click on the calendar for each month and get the data for each day which make this task complex and tricky.

Comment: The codes above only get the data for one day, which is on the first day of the specified month.  I tried to have them loop through a whole month(let's say Dec, 2021) by initiating a list `days = [str(i) for i in range(1,32)]` but I then encountered error **ElementNotInteractableException**. To my understanding, everytime we performed a click on an element the whole webpage changed its content making the element not interactable.

Comment: @ThaiNguyen, when I turned on the web dev tool network tab and selected Sulfur Dioxide in the dropdown I see some network requests like this: https://insight2-data.sonomatech.com/api/data/filterAsJson there is your API.  you'll need to figure out how to compose the data that's being sent, and how to extract the desired info from the response JSON, but I do see it there.

Comment: @ThaiNguyen and @BreaksSoftware, you may use th below to get the details from Chrome Developer Tools (only if you use Chrome Browser instead of Edge)
`caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
{your code blocks}
perf = driver.get_log('performance')`
But I am not sure if you can get data from it. As far as I know, it is the Performance tab of Developer Tools and it gives logs but not data I guess.

Comment: And you cannot use this api directly (insight2-data.sonomatech.com/api/data/filterAsJson) due to the restrictions the websites place on for security reasons

Answer (score 1):

@ThaiNguyen, adding another answer to preserve the earlier one. I tried some crude ways to get the work done, and I succeeded after a lot of attempts, but I would say take it with a pinch of salt, as I iterated only for 3 dates in Aug. The refactored code is pasted below, but before you could see the code, let me explain you what I faced, which you could flag to take care.
I had to add a lot of sleeps in order for the DOM to settle down for each action (and as you know, time.sleep is pretty unreliable when it comes to async), but I think even after waits I see that the code fails to stale elements, and adding time helped me take care of them (temporarily).
Another thing - which, per me, is a big concern: Even though this code succeeded in fetching the results, I cannot assure you that it would do so for all the dates in Aug (let alone for all the required months), for the code behaves pretty flaky with  the rendered DOM, and I don't want to blame the code at this point in time (with the limited knowledge that I have on selenium), but the DOM has heavy async if I am not wrong.
So, I would want to say that with this code, you cannot hope to get everything at one shot; rather, you may have to invest your time in either refactoring the code and improving it or fetching data in chunks by running multiple times for a few dates at a time for each month, which is very frustrating, given the flakiness it owes to.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager(log_level=20).install())
driver.maximize_window()
def h2s_selection():
    driver.get("https://marathonlosangelesrefineryfencelinemonitoring.com/index.html")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='nav-link-text']"))).click()
    # Navigate to monitors
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='arrow-down parameter-arrow']"))).click()
    # Navigate to dropdown button
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='dropdown-menu' and @role='menu' and @aria-labelledby='ParameterDropdown']//li[12]"))).click()
    # Select Hydrogen Sulfide and click
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane']//div[contains(@class, 'leaflet-marker-icon')]")))

def aug_date():
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".arrow-down.date-arrow").click()
    req_month = 'Aug'
    req_year = '2021'
    req_timeline = req_month + " " + req_year
    print(f"Timeline Selected is: {req_timeline}")
    for i in range(11):
        month = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//th[@class='month']").text
        if month == req_timeline:
            break
        else:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//th[@class='prev available']").click()
    dt = ['1', '2', '3']
    for i in dt:
        time.sleep(5)
        each_date = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='table-condensed']//td[text()=" + i + ']')
        print(f"Date is {each_date.text}")
        each_date.click()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Apply']").click()
        time.sleep(10)
        tooltips()
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".arrow-down.date-arrow").click()

def tooltips():
    # time.sleep(8)
    res = []
    test = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane']//div[contains(@class, 'leaflet-marker-icon')]")
    for ele in test:
        hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ele)
        hover.perform()
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            site_id = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-site-id > p")
            site_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-site-name")
            date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-localtime")
            value = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-data-value")
            unit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-data-unit")
            para_mdl = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".tooltip-parameter-mdl")
            res.append((site_id.text, site_name.text, date.text, value.text, unit.text, para_mdl.text))
        except:
            pass
    print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    h2s_selection()
    aug_date()
```

Output:

```
Timeline Selected is: Aug 2021
Date is 1
[('F', 'Point Monitor', '10:55 AM', '0.90', 'ppb', 'MDL: 0.40 ppb'), ('B', 'Point Monitor', '10:55 AM', '1.20', 'ppb', 'MDL: 0.40 ppb'), ('E', 'Point Monitor', '10:55 AM', '1.30', 'ppb', 'MDL: 0.40 ppb'), ('A', 'Point Monitor', '10:55 AM', '0.60', 'ppb', 'MDL: 0.40 ppb')]
Date is 2
[('B', 'Point Monitor', '10:25 PM', '1.70', 'ppb', 'MDL: 0.40 ppb'), ('E', 'Point Monitor', '10:25 PM', '1.90', 'ppb', 'MDL: 0.40 ppb')]
Date is 3
[('F', 'Point Monitor', '9:55 AM', '1.20', 'ppb', 'MDL: 0.40 ppb'), ('B', 'Point Monitor', '9:55 AM', '1.20', 'ppb', 'MDL: 0.40 ppb'), ('E', 'Point Monitor', '9:55 AM', '1.90', 'ppb', 'MDL: 0.40 ppb'), ('A', 'Point Monitor', '9:55 AM', '0.50', 'ppb', 'MDL: 0.40 ppb')]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

@AnandGautam, I realized that whenever I wanted to scrape the data for a whole month (let's say Sep 2021) everything went fine until I reached to the 29th where we had Aug 29th and Sep 29th on the same calendar. So to make the Xpath unique, I modified it a bit by adding `@data-title=`. But I encountered some errors. I tried to verify the Xpath and found it was valid so I still have no idea why the errors occurred. Please see the codes below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager(log_level=20).install())
driver.maximize_window()
def h2s_selection():
    driver.get("https://marathonlosangelesrefineryfencelinemonitoring.com/index.html")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='nav-link-text']"))).click()
    # Navigate to monitors
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='arrow-down parameter-arrow']"))).click()
    # Navigate to dropdown button
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='dropdown-menu' and @role='menu' and @aria-labelledby='ParameterDropdown']//li[12]"))).click()
    # Select Hydrogen Sulfide and click
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane']//div[contains(@class, 'leaflet-marker-icon')]")))

def month_data(req_month, req_year, data):
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".arrow-down.date-arrow").click()
    req_timeline = req_month + " " + req_year
    print(f"Timeline Selected is: {req_timeline}")
    for i in range(11):
        month = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//th[@class='month']").text
        if month == req_timeline:
            break
        else:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//th[@class='prev available']").click()
    
    for k, v in data.items():
        time.sleep(5)
        each_date = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//*[@class='table-condensed']//td[text()={k} and @data-title={v}]")
        #print(f"Date is {each_date.text}")
        each_date.click()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Apply']").click()
        time.sleep(10)
        tooltips()
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".arrow-down.date-arrow").click()

def tooltips():
    # time.sleep(8)
    res = []
    test = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane']//div[contains(@class, 'leaflet-marker-icon')]")
    for ele in test:
        hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ele)
        hover.perform()
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            site_id = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-site-id > p")
            site_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-site-name")
            date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-localtime")
            value = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-data-value")
            unit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".LAR-tooltip-data-unit")
            para_mdl = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".tooltip-parameter-mdl")
            res.append((site_id.text, site_name.text, date.text, value.text, unit.text, para_mdl.text))
        except:
            pass
    print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    h2s_selection()
    data_dict = {'29': 'r4c3', '30': 'r4c4'}
    month_data(req_month='Sep', req_year='2021', data=data_dict)
```

I really appreciate if you can give me some pointers/feedbacks on how to resolve that. Thank you!